# Insert values in an associative array but only if have value

Tags: php

I've this bucle:

```
foreach($jsonU as $j) {
        $jsonUId = $j->id;
        $jsonUName = $j->name;
        $jsonUDescription = $j->description;
        $jsonUDate = $j->date;
        $jsonUStatus = $j->status;
        $jsonUPicture = $j->picture;

        $jsonUncompleted[] = array('id'=> $jsonUId, 'name'=> $jsonUName, 'description' => $jsonUDescription, 'date' => $jsonUDate, 'status' => $jsonUStatus, 'picture' =>$jsonUPicture);
}
```

I need to insert a key in the array only if have value. For example, `$jsonUPictore` not always has a value and in that case I don't need to write that key.

Some help?

Comment: So you're saying that not all of the fields are always going to be present in the array, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `array_filter` function with or without a parameter:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Example:

```
$jsonUncompleted[] = array_filter( array(
  'id'=> $jsonUId, 'name'=> $jsonUName, 'description' => $jsonUDescription,
  'date' => $jsonUDate, 'status' => $jsonUStatus, 'picture' =>$jsonUPicture
));
```

Comment: Be careful, because without a filter parameter, it will filter out every falsy value like `0`, `""`, `false`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to remove all `NULL` values from an array there's an easy way to do it using the `array_filter` function the last poster mentioned:

```
$new_array_without_nulls = array_filter($array_with_nulls, 'strlen');
```

Source: http://briancray.com/posts/remove-null-values-php-arrays/